# 'Whenever' gem Scheduler doesn't run tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, whenever

I'm seeking help concerning the `whenever` gem. Here my case:

I have the task I generated and that works when I run it through command line as such `rake dashboard_data_t:collect`.

```
namespace :dashboard_data_t do
  desc "TODO"
  task collect: :environment do
     #task...
  end
end
```

I then followed the documentation provided [here](https://github.com/javan/whenever) in such a way that my `config/schedule.rb` looks like so:

```
# config/schedule.rb
every :day, at: '10:43 am' do
    rake "dashboard_data_t:collect"
end
```

Happily done with that, I thought it would go on and run itself alone, without me needing to do anything more. But I noticed it didn't. I thought it might come from my task so I created an other one, this time way more simple than the 1st. Its purpose was solely to experiment and find what was going wrong:

```
namespace :test_name do
  desc "TODO"
  task test_task: :environment do
    sh('echo', 'test task runned successfully')
  end
end
```

I then added the following to my `config/schedule.rb`:

```
# config/schedule.rb
every 1.minutes do
    rake "test_name:test_task"
end
```

Once again, the task didn't execute (periodically), but was still working manually.
I noticed by running the `crontab -e` command that `RAILS_ENV` was set to `production`, I understood why my `dashboard_data_t:collect` task wasn't working, because it relied on the `development` db. So I did the following:

```
# config/schedule.rb
set :environment, 'development'
```

Unfortunately, this didn't change anything as both tasks still don't execute. Now I'm stuck here with no ideas whatsoever. Can anyone help me.

Cheers.

Comment: did you forget to run `bundle exec wheneverize .`?

Comment: I didn't mention it, but it was done aswell.